# Elasticsearch multi_match comma issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search on a project to accomplish an autocomplete functionality.

Here is the deal.

If I search for, lets say, keyword = "`bird nest`", 
I am getting some results that I don't want to get like :

- x bird nest at California
- y bird nest at Atalanta
- **z bird, nest is not available** (this is the one that I don't want)

Is there any way of making elasticsearch not to match those which has comma between the words?

Here is what my query looks like.

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20,
    "sort": [
        {
            "rate": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": keyword,
                    "operator": "and",
                    "type": "phrase_prefix",
                    "fields": [ "name.en_US", "name.zh_TW","name.ja_JP","name.zh_CN" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's is your mappings? what version of ES that you using ?

Comment: @Duc.Duong its pretty old (I dont have a choice to upgrade for now). `"version": {
"number": "0.20.0.RC1",`
And my mapping : 
`"name": {
"dynamic": "true",
"properties": {
"en_US": {
"type": "string"
},
"ja_JP": {
"type": "string"
},
"zh_CN": {
"type": "string"
},
"zh_TW": {
"type": "string"
}
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

Its not the mapping that you should be looking into. Its the analyzer that plays the vital role in your case. If you are using the default standard analyzer, this is an expected result.

Please check this blog in elasticsearch website to get the solution.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/starts-with-phrase-matching/

You can use the analyze api to test how your data will be tokenized in the elasticsearch server.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?text=this+is+a+test'
```

The above will run an analysis on the "this is a test" text, using the default index analyzer associated with the test index.

An analyzer can also be provided to use a different analyzer:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=whitespace' -d 'this is a test'
```

Please check the below link for any issues on analyze api.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html

You can use the whitespace analyzer with word delimiter token filter to achieve this as far as I know. Try different parameters and test using the analyze api to get the expected result.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html

Comment: will look into this if i have time this week. I will let you know. thanks